# Display home page in base url without showing /home (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, web, laravel-4, web-hosting

If I type my website url in browser as www.test.com/ then it redirects to www.test.com/home. But I want to see the url in browser as www.test.com only.

> routes.php

```
Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'HomeController@home', 'as' => 'home'));
Route::get('home', array('uses' => 'HomeController@home', 'as' => 'home'));
```

Comment: post the code for `HomeController@home()`. also, the htaccess if apache. p.s. you have duplication in named routes. avoid that.

Comment: there are no problems with these code segment. these two routes work charm and both of them can access HomeController@home did you change your .htaccess file ? on root directory

Comment: The below shown is the code for HomeController@home
<?php

class HomeController extends BaseController {

 

 public function home()
 {
  //Session::forget('forgotfails');
  return View::make('home');
 }

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your route file:

```
Route::get('/', 'Admin\HomeController@index');
```

and remove the extra home route.

See, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'HomeController@home', 'as' => 'home'));
```

Keep this route only and remove the next route
It will work as you are expecting then

Comment: the routes are applied from top to bottom. these two routes just shares common method. deleting them won't change anything.

Comment: Why dont you give an answer instead of just  "commenting "

Comment: because the issue is in the code which he is yet to provide.

Comment: Atleast i am  trying to help

Comment: cheers for that. i only commented because, the above won't work (that aspect is intended for future reader along with op).

Comment: I have kept this route only: 
Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'HomeController@home', 'as' => 'home'));     but is shows error "This web page has a redirect loop"                                                             and my controller is given below:
  <?php

class HomeController extends BaseController {

 public function home()
 {
  Session::forget('forgotfails');
  return View::make('home');
 }

}  what is the reason for error??